# Unable to include the file, but the code does work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to print out pdf files from a MySQL database using PHP. Check this link for the 'tutorial' I'm following: https://joshuaotwell.com/php-mysql-blob-pdf-display-in-browser/

I get this warning message: Warning: include(include.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\templates\base_html.php on line 2

This happens when I try to include my 'include.php' file, where I connect to the database. The wierd thing to me is that the code does still work and prints out the name of the item in the database. Probably because it's a warning and not an error, but still. Can anyone help me how to clear this message?

Below is the code from my projects.php file.

```
<?php
include '../include.php';

$sql = "SELECT id, name
        FROM projects
        ORDER BY name ASC;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $records[] = [
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'name' => $row['name']
    ];
}
$title = 'Display PDF File';
ob_start();
include __DIR__ . "\display_html.php";
$output = ob_get_clean();

include __DIR__ . "\base_html.php";

?>
```

My directory is like this: xampp/htdocs/portfolio/templates
My include file is in the portfolio folder and the projects.php file, the code above, is in the templates folder together with the 2 folders called display_html.php and base_html.php.

Comment: _"and the projects.php file, the code above"_ - the message did not say it occurred in projects.php, but in _"... in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\templates\base_html.php on line 2"_

Comment: @CBroe You're right, I thought that referenced the include to that file, not that the error was in that file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you said, the connection happens in `include.php`. So the MySQL connection will work, this is true.

But the error you get, is for `base_html.php` as indicated in the error message.

Comment: You're sorta right, I thought that referenced the include to that file, not that the error was in that file itself. I just removed the include 'include.php'; I had there as well and that fixes it. Thanks for the push in the right direction